# Devise for Ruby on Rails, routing problems after installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have rails Rails 2.3.8 and Devise 1.0.8. I have followed the [installation instructions](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/v1.0), but when trying to access /users/sign_in for the first time after modified routes.rb, I get

```
Internal Server Error
undefined method `[]' for :users:Symbol
```

When I reload, I get

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/users/sign_up" with {:method=>:get}
```

If putting `map.devise_for :users` above other `map.`s, I get the same kind of routing errors when trying to access for example /artists or /songs.

Am I missing something?

Update: Here is the full output of `rake routes`

```
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in                               {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in                               {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}
  destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out                              {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
     new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                {:controller=>"passwords", :action=>"new"}
    edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)               {:controller=>"passwords", :action=>"edit"}
         user_password PUT    /users/password(.:format)                    {:controller=>"passwords", :action=>"update"}
                       POST   /users/password(.:format)                    {:controller=>"passwords", :action=>"create"}
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                     {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"new"}
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                        {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"edit"}
     user_registration PUT    /users(.:format)                             {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"update"}
                       DELETE /users(.:format)                             {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"destroy"}
                       POST   /users(.:format)                             {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"create"}
                 songs GET    /songs(.:format)                             {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"index"}
                       POST   /songs(.:format)                             {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"create"}
              new_song GET    /songs/new(.:format)                         {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"new"}
             edit_song GET    /songs/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"edit"}
                  song GET    /songs/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"show"}
                       PUT    /songs/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"update"}
                       DELETE /songs/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"destroy"}
          artist_songs GET    /artists/:artist_id/songs(.:format)          {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"index"}
                       POST   /artists/:artist_id/songs(.:format)          {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"create"}
       new_artist_song GET    /artists/:artist_id/songs/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"new"}
      edit_artist_song GET    /artists/:artist_id/songs/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"edit"}
           artist_song GET    /artists/:artist_id/songs/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"show"}
                       PUT    /artists/:artist_id/songs/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"update"}
                       DELETE /artists/:artist_id/songs/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"songs", :action=>"destroy"}
               artists GET    /artists(.:format)                           {:controller=>"artists", :action=>"index"}
                       POST   /artists(.:format)                           {:controller=>"artists", :action=>"create"}
            new_artist GET    /artists/new(.:format)                       {:controller=>"artists", :action=>"new"}
           edit_artist GET    /artists/:id/edit(.:format)                  {:controller=>"artists", :action=>"edit"}
                artist GET    /artists/:id(.:format)                       {:controller=>"artists", :action=>"show"}
                       PUT    /artists/:id(.:format)                       {:controller=>"artists", :action=>"update"}
                       DELETE /artists/:id(.:format)                       {:controller=>"artists", :action=>"destroy"}
                  root        /                                            {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
                              /:controller/:action/:id                     
                              /:controller/:action/:id(.:format)
```

Comment: What output do you get from running `rake routes`?

Comment: @John It looks good to me. I have updated my post with the output.

Comment: I'm on the same problem here and have not found any solutions. With this, I just can't use devise!
I'm using devise 1.0.8, rails 2.3.10, ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You know what? I've spent 10 hours on this now. And you know what?

```
killall server && script/server &
```

Now I'll kill myself aswell.